# KeyError while trying to create a list from existing list using len() function

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I am trying to create a list to calculate the number of prices in each list of list.

With the following code:

```
print data['OtherBids']
```

I got the following output:

> [[0.074, 0.073, 0.072, 0.03, 0.029, 0.024, 0.021, 0.02], [0.02, 0.02, 0.015], [0.026, 0.026, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.015], [0.021, 0.021, 0.02, 0.017], [0.077, 0.076, 0.074, 0.055, 0.045, 0.021], [0.053, 0.052, 0.051, 0.023, 0.022], [0.016, 0.016]]

Based on a cursory view of the data, we can see that there are 8 elements in the 1st list, 3 in the 2nd list, 6 in the 3rd list and so on ... However, when I tried to using a while loop to generate the data, it returned the following error:

```
data['number'][a] = len(data['OtherBids'][a])
KeyError: 'number'
```

and the code that lead to the above error are:

```
a = 0
b = len(data['OtherBids'])

while a <= b - 1:
    for i in data['OtherBids']:
        data['number'][a] = len(data['OtherBids'][a]).get
    a = a + 1
```

Anybody know how I should fix it?

Comment: Try printing `data`, it should make it clear.

Comment: You don't have a `data['number']` value.

Comment: Your `data` has no `"number"` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` has no `"number"` key:

```
a = 0
b = len(data['OtherBids'])
# add this line
data['number'] = dict()

while a <= b - 1:
    for i in data['OtherBids']:
        # seems to be mistype: len(data['OtherBids'][a]).get
        # I removed .get
        data['number'][a] = len(data['OtherBids'][a])
    a = a + 1
```

**UPD**

I found your code too complicated

More pythonic version:

```
data['number'] = {}
for i, item in enumerate(data['OtherBids']):
    data['number'][i] = len(item)
```

Inline version:

```
data['number'] = {i:len(item) for i,item in enumerate(data['OtherBids'])}
```

Comment: That's great man! Is it possible to replace the index {0,1,2,3,4,5,6} with my own key? Thanks!

Comment: @TingPing I think yes, but where you want to replace them? I mean I dont see these keys. BTW where you use `i`?

Comment: To be frank, I am just using the i to guide the program to count the next element. I am inspired by your code - need to be more pythonic!

Comment: @HansEngel agree on `{}` instead of `dict()`, but for newbies more verbose is better, I think..